# Prove: A ⋂ (B+C) = (A ⋂ B) + (A ⋂ C)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please, help me to prove this:

For $A,B,C$ subgroups in $\mathbb{Z}$:

$A\cap (B+C) = (A \cap  B) + (A \cap  C)$

All that I know about this solution is, with
 
$A=a\mathbb{Z},\ B=b\mathbb{Z},\ C=c\mathbb{Z}$,

$A + B = u\mathbb{Z}$, and $u = gcd(a,b)$

$A \cap  B = dZ$, and $d = lcm(a,b)$

I tried to rewrite this like $lcm(a,gcd(b,c)) = gcd(lcm(a,b),lcm(a,c))$, and like composition of prime powers but it didn't help me.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: *NB:* "proof" and "prove" are different words.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Can you associate $\inf$ and $\sup$ notions with $\cap$ and $+$ ones?

Comment: @Shaun sorry, bad eng and experience in the forums :"))))

Comment: @Maryam but why shoild i use inf and sup ?

Comment: By [in whole numbers group], did you mean $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. quite so

Comment: Try showing that $\max(a,\min(b,c)) = \min(\max(a,b),\max(a,c))$ for all reals $a,b,c$.

Comment: ... and try, on your notebook, to think divisibility $u|v$ as an $\leq$ relation, and prove it by parts. Afterwards, rewrite your solution in order to be published.

Answer (score 2):

As $x\mathbb{Z}=-x\mathbb{Z}$, I can suppose that all generators $a,b,c$ are positive. 
If one of them is zero, the relation is straightforward (you can write it completely as an exercise). 
Now, inside $\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}=\{1,2,\cdots\}$, divisibility relation (write it with a vertical bar) is an order relation with 
$$
lcm=max_| \mbox{ and } gcd=min_|
$$
a golden rule for any ordering $\preceq$ (with $max$ and $min$ i.e. a lattice order) is 
$$
X\preceq min(Y,Z) \Longleftrightarrow X\preceq Y \mbox{ and }  X\preceq Z\qquad (R1)
$$ 
and 
$$
max(Y,Z)\preceq X \Longleftrightarrow Y\preceq X \mbox{ and }  Z\preceq X\qquad (R2)
$$ 
this helps decompose the problem into subproblems.
Now to prove $lcm(a,gcd(b,c)) = gcd(lcm(a,b),lcm(a,c))$, you just have 
to decompose this in two parts $lcm(a,gcd(b,c)) \preceq gcd(lcm(a,b),lcm(a,c))$ and 
$lcm(a,gcd(b,c)) \succeq gcd(lcm(a,b),lcm(a,c))$,
($X\preceq Y$ being your divisibility relation $X|Y$) and use (R1-R2). 
**Another route** As you said at the end "composition of prime powers", I indicate you this route as well.
I still suppose that all generators $a,b,c$ are positive and non-zero.
Every integer $m>0$ can be written uniquely ($\mathfrak{p}$ is the set of prime numbers)
$$
m=\prod_{p\in \mathfrak{p}}p^{\nu(p,m)}
$$ 
For every $m$, let us note $\nu(?,m)$ the function $p\mapsto \nu(p,m)$. It is easily seen that 
$$
\nu(?,lcm(x,y))=sup(\nu(?,x),\nu(?,y))\mbox{ and }
\nu(?,gcd(x,y))=inf(\nu(?,x),\nu(?,y)) 
$$
so, the identity $lcm(a,gcd(b,c)) = gcd(lcm(a,b),lcm(a,c))$ amonts to show $\nu(?,LHS)=\nu(?,RHS)$ i.e, for every prime $p\in \mathfrak{p}$
$$
sup\Big(\nu(p,a),inf(\nu(p,b),\nu(p,c))\Big)=
inf\Big(sup(\nu(p,a),\nu(p,b)),sup(\nu(p,a),\nu(p,c))\Big)
$$
which is straightforward.
Hope it helps.

**Late edit** One can use, equivalently, double inclusion for $A\cap(B+C)= (A\cap B)+(A\cap C)$. One move (i.e. $\supset$) is easy and uses only elementary arguments, but the other one (i.e. $A\cap(B+C)\subset A\cap B+A\cap C$) **is specific to $\mathbb{Z}$** as it does not hold for other groups. Take, for example, $G=\mathbb{Z}^2,\ A=(1,1).G,\ B=(1,0).G,\ C=(0,1).G$, one has $A\cap(B+C)=A$ whereas $A\cap B=A\cap C=\{(0,0)\}$.

_

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try to do

Answer (score 0):

1) First show that $A\cap(B+C)\subset A\cap B+A\cap C$.

Let $x\in A\cap(B+C)$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in (B+C)$. Also let $x=z+y$ such that $y\in B$ and $z\in C$, then $y\in A\cap B$ and $z\in A\cap C$, thus $x=y+z\in A\cap B+A\cap C$.

2) Now show that $A\cap(B+C)\supset A\cap B+A\cap C$.

Let $x\in A\cap B$ and $y\in A\cap C$, then $x\in A$, $x\in B$ and $y\in A$, $y\in C$. Then we have $x+y\in A$ and $x+y\in B+C$, which means $x+y\in A\cap(B+C)$.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good proof. Could you tell me, please, why $x=z+y$? Is it always true?

Comment: @chiuki if $x\in B+C$, then some part of $x$ belongs to $B$ and other part belongs to $C$. You just assume them as $y$ and $z$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, it is clear! Thank you

Comment: @Lee As such, it is not clear why the components are still in $A$ (i.e. $z\in A$ and $y\in A$), can you elaborate this ? (in fact, this does not hold in general groups, that's why you have to add some reason more specific to $\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. yes, in general it doesn't hold. For this case we can first think of case when $y=z$, then consider case when $y\neq z$.

Comment: @Lee this last case (in general position) is more tricky and, I insist (sorry :), uses specificity of $\mathbb{Z}$, where the lattice of subgroups is, precisely, distributive. See my *late edit* as a warning.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I am familier with the example you gave in your edit. As I said before, you can go through two cases that I gave to see that for integers it holds.

Comment: @Lee ... and this does not convince you to elaborate better your text for $A\cap(B+C)\subset A\cap B+A\cap C$ ? (the thing is that, if your arguments were sufficient, we would have this property for any abelian group. I must appear something special to $\mathbb{Z}$). Do not hesitate to interact and co-elaborate, I am at your disposition.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. since in the question it is already given that we are working with integers, my argument holds for integers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108236/discussion-between-duchamp-gerard-h-e-and-lee).